# undefined function / function not found

Tags: r, function, package

I created a package for R to learn how to develop these things and I got a error that I can't resolve. I saw this error was nor uncommon but I could not find a solution.

This is the code of my package (pretty simple):

```
absconc<-function(x,a,b,...)
{
  a<-as.numeric(a)
  b<-as.numeric(b)

absconcCalc<- function(x,a,b,...)
{
    conc<- (x*a)+b
}
conc<-absconcCalc(x,a,b,...)

print.absconc<- function(x,a,b,...)
{
cat("Slope:")
cat(a,"\n")
cat("Intercept:")
cat(b,"\n")
cat("Concentration:")
cat(conc)
}
print.absconc(x,a,b)
}
```

I created the package using `package.skeleton` and it worked like a charm, even the building of the package using `R CMD build absconc` worked.

The problem was when I trying to use the package it gave me `Error: could not find function "absconc"`.
I though it was a problem coming from NAMESPACE and the export so I tried exporting the functions using `export(absconc)`. When I tried building that I got an error saying:

```
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
undefined exports: absconc, absconcCalc, print.absconc
```

I am now scratching my head to understand why my function are not recognized.
I would appreciate some help on that as this is only my first package.

EDIT: here are my files (A bit messy, sorry)
https://github.com/Frisacher/absconc

Comment: Did you place your functions in a file ending with `.R`and in the directory `R/` of your package, e.g., `R/absconc.R`?

Comment: The automatic generation of the package with `package.skeleton()` or `devtool::create()` does that a creates the `absconc.R` in the `R/` directory. Is that what you are talking about ?

Comment: Why not create a github repository with your package, so that others can more easily reproduce your problem? Note also that the braces `{}` in the code snippet above mean that only a single function (absconc) is defined; is this what your source code looks like?

Comment: Here you go ! 
also, technically (i think) I would only need and use the one function `absconc`. I do not think the other ones have to be imported...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not edit NAMESPACE by hand. Insert the line `#' @export` at the top of your R file and run `devtools::document()` in the console. This will do what is necessary for you.

Now you can execute `devtools::load_all()` and run your function.

---

More explicitly:

1) Create a folder named "R" below the root directory and create an R script that contains your function as *Martin Morgan* suggested in the comments.

2) Add a *roxygen* comment to your R script to export it:

```
#' @export

absconc<-function(x,a,b,...)
{
  a<-as.numeric(a)
  b<-as.numeric(b)
  ...
}
```

3) Execute devtools::document() in the console.

```
> devtools::document()
Updating absconc documentation
Loading absconc
Writing NAMESPACE
```

4) Load your package with devtools::load_all().

```
> devtools::load_all()
Loading absconc
```

5) Run your function.

```
> absconc(1,2,3)
Slope:2 
Intercept:3 
Concentration:5
```

Comment: Ideally, you could read the beautiful book of Hadley Wickham on R packages!  These two sections, in particular, are related:
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-functions

Comment: I did have a look at these documents but it is hard to get and apply everything at once :)
I also tried using your methods but the NAMESPACE generated is blank (apart from the "generated by..."). I tried running the rest but the function is still not found. SO I guess the function is actually not exported.

Comment: See my edited answer. If you read the "Workflow" in each section, you should be solid!

Comment: hallelujah ! It worked this time ! It seems that using both `package.skeleton` and `devtools` doesn't work...

strangely enought when I look at the `.R` file generated from `package.skeleton()` this is what it looks like :
    .Random.seed <-
`c(403L, 10L, 728813163L, 164586458L, 126858396L, -87925089L, 
1276212469L, -74828404L, -849743774L, 1006559293L,     1611651767L,67010398L, -922752872L, 756724731L, -200900199L, 1974649384L, -103435562L, -1051871407L, 1754364419L, 1506864530L, 629111588L, 
-845046297L, 323779133L,`